# SQL command insert where not exists allows 2 identical records to be stored in database

Tags: database, sql-insert

I have a problem with an application that runs on a machine in my factory(where I work I mean).

Anyway the application creates unique numbers for packages which are tied to unique box numbers which they are loaded into. As such they should always be unique numbers.

Now it was seen in the report file that 2 box numbers where identical and the components within. That means that 2 numbers where loaded into the database table from where the report is generated.

Now the coding part 
The programmers of the application want to solve this by using the

SELECT DISTINCT sql command

from the database to generate the file so that it will only ever write one version of the double registered number. (This is because we don't know how the number was put into the database twice) I don't want this solution because it is only treating one known symptom and not the cause. There might be other effects that we are not aware of.

I have suggested that they use

INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS sql command

so that the same item can never be registered.

Now they return to me and say that that condition already exists....? I cant understand that is it possible?

The only scenario I can think of is that it is not just the field of the number but a combination of fields that they perform the INSERT WHERE NOT EXISTS.

Is it possible that a command can fail in another way? I have no access to the code so I cant give an example of it but my problem is a concrete one. I don't want to be railroaded by them so that is why I am asking you guys.

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Postgres? Oracle? Why don't you just create a unique index and prevent duplicates permanently?

Comment: because this duplicate data has already been inserted perhaps the programmers mean that they are just going to select back using distinct. Of course it is likely that if this happened once it will happen again in which case they need to amend the code as you have suggested.

Comment: Hi guys, i Think we would be able to delete existing database entries as they are first used once they go into the report file so I am going to suggest this. The database is mssql 2008

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems probable that this is a concurrency problem.

The statement

```
insert into [] where not exists []
```

could be submitted twice at the same time and run in parallel. Both statements check their condition and then both insert. This may be more exposed by having long running transactions.

To uncover the bug (something *will* fail somewhere) actually tell the database that this value is meant to be unique. First you would ofcourse have to remove duplicates, then you could for example use a

```
create unique index on [ ]
```

Comment: This seems to be the answer so I am going to discuss it with them,but why won't concurrency affect the unique command, is it that there is some hash table for the id or something that it checks against before inserting that hash value must not be used or something?

Comment: Depending on the database, this is in one way or another enforced by locks. While one (the first transaction to execute the statement) creates and holds the lock, the other transactions blocks and continues when that lock is released. Again depending on the implementation, the use of transactions, the error handling, other stuff may fail or still happen twice, look out for that. Depending on what else happens inside the transaction, expect deadlocks.